# Long word didn't hyphenate

Tags: beamer, line-breaking

I'm sure it would be quite easy to answer it but currently, I'm sorry that I couldn't to do that, I'm using beamer packages are given below there is a word that used "demonstrated" I'm trying to break it so that two lines equally balance document i.e., justify. I use " \- " it worked but it just split the word without hyphenate then I used the \hyphenation{demonst-rated}, the word disappears. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\hyphenation{words}
\hyphenation{demonstrated}
\usepackage{microtype}
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\olditem\vspace{8pt}}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{romannum}
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block alerted begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}

\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{1\textwidth}%
}{}
```

Comment: To force breaking, use `\-`, not just a dash.

Comment: I used the same now I modified the question.

Comment: Please post a small compilable code reproducing the problem.

Comment: The default hyphenation is "demon-strated".  A usable pattern for the preamble would be `\hyphenation{dem-on-stra-ted}`.  The break you suggest (after "st") wouldn't be proper for English.